# Optional parameters for form filling in Dialogflow CX

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I cannot seem to get dialogflow CX to fill out optional parameters, only when they are required.
I want to have the bot ask the user for input, like "Tell me about your experience", and then repeat it back to them, but also give the user the ability to skip the question.

I have tried different solutions for solving this. One solution was to have a requires sys.any parameter and then check if it contains the word "skip" or not. However, that does not seem very robust, as a valid comment could result in a skip if they used that word.

My second attempt is seen in image 1. I tried to have a sys.any parameter which is not required and also a custom "skip" entity which was not required. No matter what I said, it would result in default fallback. I also tried to have an intent for skipping (called "no") which would overrule sys.any if it were required. However, it is just recorded in the "AnyInput" parameter, no matter what I say.

What would be a good way to give the user the ability to make a comment or skip it? Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmhxd.png)

Comment: First thing, If you want a question is 'skippable' you should let user know while asking or some way in advance so they should be aware that they can skip the question. Unless its will be very hard to track the next movement of the user. Yeah playing with word is not a good idea, mean a user can say 'It was not a good day, I skipped running today'.

Comment: The user will be notified that they can skip the question. But is there a way to make a better condition than if the input just contains the word skip? Kinda like an intent, where certain phrases will be matched.

Comment: I guess it simple then, if as a user I know I can skip the question I can say anything related to skip. like ['I don't want to answer, please skip', 'what next ?', 'ask me later', 'ask another question', 'move next', 'try tomorrow', 'I will pass this one' , 'move ahead' ].

You can make intent based on these keywords for for response, create a child dialog/intent to handle that.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how to approach this. If I make an intent with such phrases ("skip", "no comment", "go to next question") and add the parameter "AnyInput" as required (otherwise it won't register and go to default fallback) it will overrule the "skip question" intent and log the user's response in the sys.any parameter, despite matching the intent.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.